# How would I go about creating an app that can change python code from within the app?

Tags: python, excel, windows, macos, web-scraping

This might be hard to explain so stay with me, I've created a web scraper that scrapes a specific site for information, the code looks like this -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}

questionlist = []

def getQuestions(tag, page):
    url = f'https://www.merinfo.se/search?d=c&ap=1&emp=0%3A20&rev=0%3A100&who={tag}&bf=1&page={page}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    questions = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'box-white p-0 mb-4'})
    for item in questions:
        question = {
        'tag': tag,
        'title': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-primary'}).text,
        'link': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-primary'})['href'],
        'nummer': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-body'})['href'],
        'address': item.find('address', {'class': 'mt-2 mb-0'}).text,
        'RegÅr': item.find('div', {'class': 'col text-center'}).text,
        }
        questionlist.append(question)
    return

for x in range(1,6):
    getQuestions('bygg', x)
    #getQuestions('advokat', x)

df = pd.DataFrame(questionlist)
df.to_excel('merinfo skrapare för bygg.xlsx')
print('LBC Marketing TM')
```

what I would like to do is create a simple application that can change this part

```
for x in range(1,6):
    getQuestions('bygg', x)
    #getQuestions('advokat', x)
```

mainly the ('bygg') and range (1,6) part. It doesn't have to be pretty but just something that works, and something that I can make pretty in the future. I'm not asking for a full on tutorial (although that would be nice) but just some pointers in the right direction so I know what to search for since I am really new to all this.

Cheers!

Comment: You seem to be taking the wrong approach. You don't want to change the code - rather, change its behaviour. You should consider the range and first parameter to getQuestions as being configurable. So, when that piece of code is about to be executed you need to acquire those data from somewhere else. A configuration file perhaps!

Comment: At what point do you know what the values for range and the string need to be? Can you use command line parameters from `sys.argv`?

Comment: I clicked on this question half expecting to close it, but was pleasantly surprised. Aside from trying to overcomplicate the solution, this is a nice question and well posed. Good work OP

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you! I literally started coding yesterday so I'm still trying to figure everything out, these responses are amazing and I am greatful, although I don't understand what they mean xD

Comment: Keep reading the tutorials and playing around until it becomes easy

Comment: Is there anything specific that I can search for to find a solution? Is it function work or passing value work or what does this entail?

Comment: Read about functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a function and pass the parts you want to change as parameters. There is no need for "self modifying" or even generated code just for this:

```py
def get_results(field, start, stop):
    results = []
    for x in range(start, stop):
        results.append(getQuestions(field, x))
    return results

get_results('bygg', 1, 6)
get_results('advokat', 1, 10)
```

the values that get passed to `get_results` can come from a CSV file, or anyother place- just code that.

Comment: When I say I'm new I mean I literally started yesterday, no programming experience what so ever before that. Where in the code does the def part fit in? And why?